# How to invoke a @RolesAllowed protected method from an EJB Timer?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I have a Method annotated with `@RolesAllowed`, this method needs to be invoked from an timer (`@Schedule`), that is located in an other Ejb. But I only get a Authorization Exception: `WARNUNG: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation`

```
 @RolesAllowed("user")
 @Stateless
 public class RatingService {
    public void recalculateRating() {...}
 }

 @Singleton
 @Startup     
 public class TimerService {

     @EJB private RatingService ratingService;

     @Schedule(minute = "0", hour = "*")
     public void timerTriggeredRecalculate() {        
          this.ratingService.recalculateRating();
     }
 }
```

I accept this exception, but **how to invoke a `@RolesAllowed` protected method from a Timer?**

---

---

*I also tryed to add `@RunAs("user")` to the `TimerService` Class. But then I get this exception:*

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: SECEJB9000: Exception while running pre-invoke
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3357)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3343)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm.getGroupNames(FileRealm.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.loginPrincipal(LoginContextDriver.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager$2.run(EJBSecurityManager.java:825)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.common.AppservAccessController.doPrivileged(AppservAccessController.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loginForRunAs(EJBSecurityManager.java:823)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.preInvoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:791)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EjbSecurityComponentInvocationHandler$1.beforePreInvoke(EjbSecurityComponentInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.preInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:156)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:487)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

*The Server is a Glassfish 3.1.2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use an EJB that is annotated `@RunAs`.  If the timer method is the only method exposed by the `TimerService` EJB, then you could add the `@RunAs` to that class directly.  Otherwise, you'll need to create an intermediate `PrivilegedRatingService` EJB that has the `@RunAs`.

(As an aside `TimerService` is probably a poor choice for an EJB class name given the conflict with `javax.ejb.TimerService`.)

Comment: This is what I tryed "I also tryed to add @RunAs("user") to the TimerService Class. But then I get this exception:..." (lower part of my question). So if this would be the correct way, do you have an idea why I get this exception?

Comment: No, I don't know.  It looks like a product issue, so I would recommend opening a bug.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tryed to add @RunAs("user") to the TimerService Class. But then
>   I get this exception: ..

The message suggest that you haven't defined "user" in your file realm. For example, in Glassfish, use application server console to access the following:

`Configuration->Security->Realms->file->Manage users`

and add new user "user" - the error message should disappear. I had similar problem and this was the solution, so maybe helps.